# Windows experience Index

Tags: windows

Can you download and run Windows experience index on XP machines? We're looking at upgrading some of our machines at work and want to identify the trouble spots in an easy way.

Word on the street is that it only runs in Vista/7, but I can't find any solid confirmation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/upgrade-advisor.aspx). AFAIK this won't give you an Experience score, but will spot other potential problems

Comment: Here's link to the Vista Upgrade Advisor

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No, not that I've ever seen.  This is a Vista / Win7 specific thing since it's mainly targeted at the Aero theme.  Have a read through [**this article**](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowsvista/pages/windows-experience-index-an-in-depth-look.aspx) which gives an in-depth explanation of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just thought Id mention my experience with the Windows Experience Index.

Not so long ago I received three **brand new carbon copy** vostro laptops from Dell. I set all three up on a bench besides each other and performed the initial setup of Vista identically on all three (excluding obvious stuff like computer names etc =D ).

Poking around the computer properties page I decided to run the Windows experience index and see what they got. I thought that it wouldn't be likely that they were all identical but they should be reasonably close. So after they finished doing the test all three laptops showed different numbers to each other. Laptop A showed 3.4, B showed 3.2 and C showed 2.8.

Now call me crazy but that seriously makes me think that the whole Windows Experience Index thing is a complete joke.

Comment: This is very interesting to be able to test on identical machines. Did you do much followup after the initial tests? Did you run defrag on each machine perhaps?

Comment: I didn't do too much follow up afterwards (because I had to get the laptops ready for use). But I did have all three laptops side by side the whole time. I basically ran the tests as soon as I go into Vista. I really can't think of any variable that would have produced such different results in such a controlled environment.

Ghosts in the machine perhaps? Or just a lowsy tool made by M$? =)

Comment: Which component was showing different scores between the three machines?  The base score is determined by the lowest subscore of the following components: Processor, RAM, Graphics, Gaming Graphics, and Primary Hard Disk.